# AMP login popup submit error

Tags: amp-html

I try to simulate AMP login/logout on my local, but not understand exactly what i must to do after popup login is submitted.

I followed the example  when trying to simulate example from https://ampbyexample.com/samples_templates/comment_section/preview/ and if submit validate the login, then i redirect to a page login-done.html?url={redirecturl}#success=true . {redirecturl} is the opener url .

In this page (login-done.html?url={redirecturl}#success=true) I have added  .
But nothing happen after redirect and have these errors:

> amp-login-done-0.1.js:57 Postback failed: Error: Timed out at
>   amp-login-done-0.1.js:55 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set
>   property 'onclick' of null at Gc.l (amp-login-done-0.1.js:57)

I see that I get timeout because https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ampproject/amphtml/1493083583453/build/all/v0/amp-login-done-dialog.js" not found 404.

If I refresh the main page (opener) the amp-access working. I reffer to the section:

```
<section amp-access="NOT loggedIn" amp-access-hide role="button" tabindex="0">
    Please <a class="btn" on="tap:amp-access.login-sign-in">Login</a> to comment.
</section>
<section amp-access="loggedIn" amp-access-hide role="button" tabindex="0">
  <a class="btn" on="tap:amp-access.login-sign-out">Logout</a>
</section>
```

Of course, i can reload the opener and I get the "Logout" btn visible if login was successful, but in example seems that there is not a reload of the the main page and amp-access authorization is called from popup. Login/Logout buttons are changed without to refresh the page.

I apreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong URL in your login page. The correct one is: `https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-login-done-0.1.html`. For example:

```
<input name="returnurl" type="hidden" value="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-login-done-0.1.html?url=https%3A%2F%2Fampbyexample.com%2Fsamples_templates%2Fcomment_section%2Fpreview%2F">
```